# In qooxdoo code, how do I force ie and edge always refresh from the server?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, qooxdoo

I can do it in browser:
 Press F12 to open the Developer Tools. Switch to network and activate the "always refresh from the server" option, but how to do it in code ?

Comment: What approach towards caching have you taken in your HTTP responses?

Comment: I think I'll have to do something like this:                                                      if (document.documentMode || /Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
               headers: {'Content': 'no-cache'}
            }

Answer (score 1):

you mean how you can for the javascript to be reloaded when you deploy a new version of your code?

I update my index.html to load

```
app.js?version=1.2.23
```

in that way I always get the correct code loaded.

Comment: Thanks Tobi but I didn't mean how to deploy.